# Trigger Jenkins Pipeline on Pull Request

Tags: jenkins, github

I have a Github personal account. I have configured Jenkins to trigger build on the PUSH event. I want to do the same on the Pull Request event and later for new branch event. How to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article can help you to trigger build when code pushed in Github.

https://oncomputingwell.princeton.edu/2018/01/triggering-a-jenkins-build-every-time-changes-are-pushed-to-a-git-branch-on-github/

And this can help to trigger build when pull request accepted

https://dev.to/webhookrelay/automated-jenkins-builds-on-github-pull-request-4lh2

I used this for mine projects too

Hope this can help you