# Jenkins - how to trigger mulitbranch pipeline once the pull request is Created?

Tags: jenkins

we have multiple branches (e.g. branch1, branch2...) and each of them can be merged to master.
Once the pull request is **created** (not in the moment when it is **accepted/merged**) we want to run a pipeline.
How to set this up?
I found this link
[Trigger Jenkins Pipeline on Pull Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61039341/trigger-jenkins-pipeline-on-pull-request)
but it explains in cases when pull request is **accepted**!

Thank you!

Comment: You can create a Webhook that triggers your Pipeline on PR create events.

Comment: I am using Bitbucket as git server. Can you please help me what is exactly expected in Jenkins URL? I am not sure what is exactly the path.
`https://jenkins.domain/cap/job/GETraining/job/devops20/job/test/job/testing7/job/feature%252Ftest/`

Comment: my pipeline is being executed automatically once I do some push on specific branch. That works out of the box once I specific repo. But if I introduce pull request configuration "only branches that are files as PRs" when new PR is created this does not trigger automatically. can it be that Bitbucket is set only for sending pushes and not PRs? I do not have any webhook defined on project level, so I suppose that maybe this is some general company policy